# Always off Bit AB

Tags: plc

Using AB 5000 and wondering how I load an always off bit?  I know in AB 500 i could use the system resource bit  P_OFF i think it was.. What is the same in 5000?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can do the following (true and false can be any internal Boolean):

```
true := true or not true;
false := not true;
```

Here it is in ladder:

[image]

Comment: You don't need this; just use the empty rung.

Comment: That's true for AB PLCs. Not all plc's allow empty rungs with an output.

Comment: Agreed, but OP did specifically ask about AB.

Answer (score 3):

There is not always off *bit*, but there is the `AFI` instruction instead.

Answer (score 0):

An empty rung with an output bit (call it T)  is enough; that output bit will always be True.  Simply refer to T (if you want TRUE) or the complement of T (if you want FALSE).